# How do you say "officer is downgraded" or "lowered" in status?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the corps (Police, army, ...) there are grades that go from Private, lieutenant, ... general.

What do you say when some officer rank is lowered in status?

Say that he is a General and for bad behaviour he is taken back to be a Private.

Comment: That would have to be some incredibly bad behavior.

Comment: [See General demoted to Lt Colonel](http://www.armytimes.com/news/your-army/2016/12/16/two-star-general-demoted-after-affair/):  "An Army spokesman says [the Maj. Gen.]  was demoted by three steps to the rank of lieutenant colonel, a steep and rare downgrade for a senior officer".  See [here](http://1914-1918.invisionzone.com/forums/topic/205715-officers-demoted/) for Lt demoted to private in WWI.

Comment: [**Cashiered**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cashier) Came to mind, but my memory (incorrectly) made me think that it could result in an officer being reduced to enlisted status.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins *Cashiering* represents dismissal (and originally with  the loss of the cash amount spent purchasing the commission, hence the word).  *Degradation* might be more appropriate, but I think *demotion* is a less intense alternative

Comment: Going below Captain (or Lt. (Cap.), Ensign, or equivalent) means losing your commission. I cannot see any way this could feasibly happen: the general is dismissed for some reason (retirement or gross misconduct or something), the army then becomes so desperate that they re-enlist (presumably via draft) the person but their faculties have degraded such that they aren't exempt from service yet only qualify as Private.

Comment: @ab2 - they weren't demoted: they were dismissed and then (forcibly) re-enlisted.

Comment: "I am altering your rank, pray I don't alter it any further."

Comment: In most modern militaries you can't demote an officer to an enlisted rank, AFAIK.

Comment: Ranking up is usually called "promote", and the opposite of promote is "demote".

Answer (score 130, accepted):

> How do you say when some officer get's his rank lowered the status?.
>
> Say that he is a General and for bad behaviour his is taken back to be
>   a Private

The noun would be "demotion", the verb "demote".

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demote

Comment: Common slang for this in the US is "busted" - "He was busted back down to Private."

Comment: @JeffZeitlin:  Good point, but it might be worth clarifying that this slang is always used with the preposition "down".  "He was busted to private" wouldn't be idiomatic.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: "Busted" without "down" is actually well attested. I'm not sure if it's regional or dialectal or what.

Comment: @ruakh Doesn't it usually refer to some variation of being *caught* or *arrested*?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - A good point in response. Yes, "busted" for rank is almost invariably accompanied by *down*; perhaps I should have written that the slang is "busted down" instead of just "busted". Without the "down", and without an explicit rank indication, it could mean (as can-ned_food points out) "caught" or "arrested".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "busted back" is a variation I've seen, e.g. "He was busted back to Private".

Comment: @can-ned_food: No -- I mean yes, *to bust* has plenty of more-common meanings -- but I meant that it's well attested in the sense we're talking about here. (Google "busted to private" and "busted him to private" for plenty of examples.)

Comment: "Motion" - to move, "De-" prefix for undoing, going backwards, down, etc. Contrasted with "Promotion" - moving upward.

Comment: There is also the racist term "[Irish promotion](https://books.google.ca/books?id=dqyqialyUyMC&pg=PA9&dq=%22Irish+promotion%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Irish%20promotion%22&f=false)" to mean demotion

Comment: @can-ned_food Not exclusively. "busted down/back" is one counterexample, calling someone a ["ball-buster"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ball-buster) is another (in this case, "to bust" is meant as "to break", and "ball-breaker" is an accepted synonym)

Answer (score 13):

In the British army the phrase is ***reduced to the ranks***.

The following is the OED entry on the very term:

> b. orig. Mil. to reduce to (formerly also †into) the ranks: to demote
>   (a non-commissioned officer) to the rank of private; (more generally)
>   to strip (any officer or official) of his or her seniority; to demote.
>   Also in extended use.>
>
> ?1758   C. W. Direct. Execution Militia Act 9   To serjeants to be
>   reduced into the ranks, which is the purport of this clause.
>
> 1768   Gen. Wolfe's Instr. Young Officers 58   The lieutenant-colonel
>   is determined to reduce to the ranks all such as are wilfully
>   negligent, or too ignorant for their stations.
>
> 1800   Caledonian Mercury (Electronic text) 20 Dec.   Before this took
>   place, the Emperor [sc. the Czar of Russia] met him, and in
>   consequence, he was reduced to the ranks, and his servant made an
>   officer in his place.
>
> 1844   Queen's Regulations & Orders Army 149   Non-commissioned
>   Officers may be reduced to the Ranks by the Sentence of a Regimental
>   or other Court-Martial.
>
> 1869   T. W. Higginson Malbone ii. 69   The girls complained that in
>   private theatricals no combination of disguises could reduce Kate to
>   the ranks, nor give her the ‘make-up’ of a waiting-maid.
>
> 1908   S. M. Crothers By Christmas Fire v. 208   He rebukes even the
>   Captains of Industry, and when they answer insolently, he suggests
>   that they be reduced to the ranks.
>
> 1967   S. Mackay Old Crow vi. 31   She had once deprived a vicar of
>   his living and, as a girl, had a captain reduced to the ranks.
>
> 1993   S. McAughtry Touch & Go vii. 54   Instead of being reduced to
>   the ranks and put on shithouse fatigues, he was transferred to Air-Sea
>   Rescue on Walrus amphibians.

Comment: The OED generalizes as "to demote", but I would not use this expression when the destination rank is not "in the ranks". It's perfect for the example of general to private, but in my humble opinion not appropriate for a captain demoted to lieutenant.

Comment: @Law29 Originally that appears to have been the case. However nowadays it has taken on a more general meaning of demotion - perhaps because it carries a sense of drama.

Comment: Demote is just the antonym of Promote. It has no other special use or meaning. Just as a Private might be promoted to Corporal or Captain to a Major, so a Sargeant might be Demoted to Corporal and a General to Colonel.

Answer (score 3):

Not single word answers but within the non-commissioned ranks you would talk of someone "losing a stripe" or "losing his stripes" and I have even heard of someone losing a pip when reduced in rank within the lower commissioned ranks.

For someone who committed a serious enough offence to lose their commission without simply being either jailed or dishonourably discharged, (a delicate balancing act), they would be "stripped of their commission" -- *note that this is not the same as being decommissioned.* Or, if busted all the way back to private, "stripped of all rank".

I think I can remember a case or two in the history books where an officer was stripped of all rank before being hung or shot *usually for cowardice*, either because 1 officer stripped of commission and 1 enlisted man shot is better in the reports than an officer shot, or to add ignominy to the punishment.

Finally we get to the single word answer **[cashiered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cashiering)** - i.e. stripped of all rank or position due to some misconduct but with the additional connotations of a ritual humiliation thrown it.

Comment: I think you meant "losing", not "loosing". At least it would match the connotation of what the poster was asking. That depends on whether or not the subject of the conversation intended to lose rank. Isn't English fun?

Comment: @Suncat2000 - Spot on - that is what I get for posting at 3:30 a.m.